# How to get battery percentage without using Receiver

Tags: android

I want to get battery percentage directly without using `BroadcastReceiver` i.e. without using `Intent`.

Using the below code we can get it but for that we have to register receiver or add a receiver in manifest file. Is there any other way to get battery percentage.

```
int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
```

Thanks

Comment: not that i know of. That is a system broadcast so you need to use a broadcast receiver and get the intent extra

Comment: read this http://www.androprogrammer.com/2013/12/how-to-get-battery-statelevel.html

Comment: @Abdulla link you have provided uses registerReceiver.

Comment: Ah ok. I don't know about android. i just try to give a tip : ) Sorry about it

Comment: I think there is no other way..but there is a pure native app way....http://code.metager.de/source/xref/android/4.1.1/frameworks/base/services/jni/com_android_server_BatteryService.cpp